# ¿Existe un tipo "time" que represente tal que HH:mm en SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Soy principiante de SQL y estoy creando una tabla , mi duda es que tengo definidas mi horaInicio y horaFin como **VARCHAR2** para introducirle una hora , las cuales corresponden a unas clases(de un gimnasio) , ¿que sería más correcto crearlo con algún tipo *time* , o con con *VARCHAR2* e introducirle horaInicio y horaFin a cada clase manualmente con un **INSERT INTO?**

```
CREATE TABLE CLASES(
OID_CL SMALLINT,
nombre VARCHAR2(20),
horaInicio VARCHAR2(10),
horaFin VARCHAR2(10),
disponibilidadClase VARCHAR2(20),
codigo VARCHAR2(6),
PRIMARY KEY(OID_CL),
FOREIGN KEY(codigo) REFERENCES REGISTRO_CLASES
);
```

Comment: bufff qué chungo! haha Lo mejor es utilizar `datetime` sin duda alguna. Piensa que aunque sólo te interesa la *hora* luego puedes utilizar `datepart` y otras funciones propias del SQL que te hacen la vida fácil y **rápida**.

Comment: Hola Miquel , podrías ponerme un ejemplo de como podría usar eso? Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teóricamente, un tipo de dato `time` es más correcto que un `varchar2` porque va a representar mejor el dato internamente en la base de datos y te va a dar la flexibilidad de utilizar algunas herramientas que pueden ser convenientes (como funciones para manipular tiempo como [`DATEDIFF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) o [`DATEADD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx))

La pregunta que debes hacerte es "¿Para qué voy a usar esos campos?". Si los vas a usar para realizar operaciones de horas y/o fechas (calcular el tiempo que dura la clase o si hay conflicto entre clases), definitivamente usa un `time`. Si sólo los vas a usar para mostrarlos por pantalla, realmente te es indiferente el tipo de dato que escojas (aunque técnicamente `time` sería lo correcto, y seguramente llegará un momento en el que te será más conveniente).

Comment: Gracias Alvaro me sirvió bastante tu información

Answer (score 1):

Si vas a utilizar únicamente hora, minutos, segundos y/o nanosegundos, utiliza [time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx), al fin y al cabo, pese a que es mínima la diferencia, a gran escala siempre van a resultar mas lentas las consultas cuando tienes datos sobrantes (la fecha en este caso).

Echa un ojo a la [documentación oficial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx) y así podrás ver las diferencias. Para empezar time tiene mas precisión en nanosegundos que datetime. A su vez, por otra parte, existe datetime2, que extiende un datetime normal con la precisión de un time en ns.

Comment: Añadir que respondiendo 100% a tu pregunta, es mas correcto utilizar time, de este modo, en la mayoría de los lenguajes tratarán el dato como un objeto time/date/datetime, evitando tener que parsearlos manualmente para utilizar funciones propias.

Comment: Gracias me sirvió amigo!